# Prove using a combinatorial argument that $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n} \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs

Prove, using a combinatorial argument, that the numbers below are integers for any natural $n$: $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$$

**Attempt:**
Suppose we organize a queue with $2n$ people, this can be done in $(2n)!$ ways. Now, from these possibilities, we take the pairing possibilities of each pair of people, for example, the first with the second, third with the fourth and etc... so we will have $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$$ But since the order doesn't matter, we have $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$$, which implies that $2^n|2n!$

I'm Right?

Comment: Your solution seems close to correct, but I don't understand what is the purpose of the last step and what do you mean by "we take the pairing possibilities of each pair of people". Could you clarify?

Comment: It's not correct that there are $2^n$ ways of pairing $2n$ people.  For example, there are $3$ ways (not $4$ ways) to divide $4$ people into pairs.

Comment: @RobertShore Is it correct to say that there are $2^n$ ways to measure the $n$ pairs of people? I can choose or not to pair AB from AB, CD, HE for example.

Comment: I think what you might be trying to say is How many lists of $n$ pairs of people can you make from $2n$ people:  You can line the people up into a list of $n$ *ordered* pairs in $(2n)!$ ways.  Given an such list there are $2^n$ ways to order the pairs.  If list of pairs are considered equivalent regardless of order there are $\frac {(2n)!}{2^n}$ to make such and *ordered* list of *unordered* pairs... oh, actually I see waht you are trying to do.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is: How many ways are there to make sets of pairs of people from $2n$ people.  You can line them up in $(2n)!$ and have those be a list of ordered pairs.  As there are $2^n$ to order the list of pairs and $n!$ to put the pairs in a list then there are $\frac {(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$ ways to do it.... although if we don't have to consider the list of pairs to be unordered with can list the pairs (ordered) in $\frac {(2n)!}{2^n}$ ways as in my comment above.

Comment: ... so is what you are trying to say is if you have four people A,B,C,D and you wanted sets of pairs there are $\{(A,B),(C,D)\}, \{(A,C),(B,D)\}, \{(A,D), (B,C)\}$ or $3 = \frac {4!}{2^2\cdot 2!}$ ways to do it? ..... [(Alternatively this shows that ${2n\choose 2}\cdot {2n-2\choose 2}\cdot{2n-4\choose 2}....\cdot{4\choose 2}\cdot {2\choose 2} = \frac {(2n!)}{2^nn!}$... which we could have proven as a telecoping product, I think)]

Comment: @fleablood That's right, thanks for explaining. I meant the last option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Line up $2n$ people in $(2n)!$ ways,
- Take out two at a time serially to get $n$ pairs
- Two ways to assign a leader from each such pair

This represents $\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n}$, and obviously must be an integer for  $n \in N$

Comment: Why do you divide it by $2^n$? What does this ratio represent?

Comment: @Mateo: Isn't it clear from the answer ?

Comment: No, it isn't. You've written that THIS represents ..., but I don't know what is this THIS. Does it the number of ways of making $n$ pairs with a leader in each of the pair?

Comment: @Mateo: Line up $2n$ people which can be done  in $(2n)!$ ways, take out two at a time serially for each such line up and assign a leader for each such pair

Answer (score 3):

You have $2n$ people and you are going to divide them into $n$ distinguishable pairs. This can be done on
$$\binom{2n}{2,2,2,\ldots,2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2!2!2!\ldots 2!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$$ ways. You can derive this formula by these two ways:

- First you arrange them in a row of length $2n$ on $(2n)!$ ways. Then you make pairs: first with second, third with fourth and so on. Then you observe that changing two people in a pair doesn't change the pair but both these arrangements participated in the initial arrangement in a row. There you have to divide the number by $2^n$.
- You choose the first pair on $\binom{2n}2$ ways. Next on $\binom{2n-2}{2}$ ways, and so on. Then you have
  $$\binom{2n}2\cdot \binom{2n-2}2\cdots \binom{4}2\cdot \binom{2}2 = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$$  ways.

Comment: @RobertShore, I don't agree.